# React router has stuck to one component irrespective of URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am trying to render **login component** at '/' URL and **dashboard component** at '/db' URL. But
after defining all the routes and implementing BrowserRouter, no matter what the URL I provide the output remains the same. I am providing the codes after the pictures of output I am getting please take note of the URL

here is the view when I am using '/' as URL
[image]

This is the view when I am using '/db' as URL
[image]

It doesn't matter what URL I enter the render remains the same.
my index.js codes go as below

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js go like as below

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import {Route,Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from './components/Login/Login';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';


class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (
    
      <div className="App">
      <h1>hello</h1>
       <Switch>
          <Route Path="/db" exact component={Dashboard}/>  
          <Route Path="/"  component={Login}/>            
       </Switch>     
      </div>
      
    );
  }
 
}

export default App;
```

Login.js go like

```
import React from 'react';

const Login = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>login</h1>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Login;
```

dashboard.js go like

```
import React from 'react';

class Dashboard extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                This is Dashboard
                
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write **path** instead of *Path* in your App.js file :)

it`s **case sensitive**

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about the capital case of `Path` property?
Try the following

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/db" exact component={Dashboard}/>  
  <Route path="/"  component={Login}/>            
</Switch>
```